# Get Power BI workbook icon using REST API

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-rest-api

I'm using REST API described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/admin/groups-get-group-as-admin to fetch/post data from/to Power BI app in my tenant.

It is possible to set custom image for the workspace manually, from web UI.

[image]

Is there a way to get image which is used as icon for Power BI workbook using REST API?

The reason is that if I'd like to copy workspace programmatically. There is API to create workspace, so I'd like to copy it with the "source" image/icon.